# Showing Who is online in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best simple way to show who is online in c# without using membership control?
Is the only way is using session ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via:

```
var onlineUsers = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser>()
    .Where(user => user.IsOnline);
```

But you will need to cache/refresh this properly, since it can be a very expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

yes go to global.asax and create a new `List<>` of your User Class type in application_start event and save it to Cache

```
    List<User> OnlineUsers = new List<User>();
    Cache.Insert ("onlineuser",OnlineUsers,...);
```

and in your loginButton code get the list from cache and add the logged in user

```
    User loggedin =someHelperCode.GetUser (txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text);
    ((List<User>)Cache["onlineuser"]).Add (loggedin);
```

and when a user logs out do the same and remove the user

and you can just bind the list to any lost bound control

Comment: What happens if the user is logged out because their session expires rather than having explicitly logged out? (beaten by Kaf - must type faster next time)